# Comment formatting FAQ does not mention notification-stripping

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, editing-help

The [comment notification FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) does not mention that notifications will be stripped from comments in some cases.

This is confusing because the line length limit takes effect after removal of notification, so a user may have written: `@SomeUser: OK!!` (15 chars) and be told that it's not long enough, because `OK!!` is only 4 chars.

<strike>It also does not mention that you may no longer notify more than one person per comment (unless there is a backtick in the comment).</strike> [covered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90576/in-the-inline-comment-help-please-mention-that-only-one-reply-is-allowed)]

This documentation must be updated — a passing comment in some bug answer somewhere on meta is not good enough.